# "You must enter a valid value" for Input type="number" with correct number

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

This code produces an invalid response in IE11:

```
<form onsubmit="alert('Valid Number!');return false;">
<input type="number" step="0.01" value="9583.89" min="0" max="10000" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

And a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pvsojuhs/

Expected output is "Valid Number!" but it seems that IE11 thinks that this is an invalid number.

Is there a work-around for this issue? Other numbers like "9583.19" work fine.

Some other test:

- 8192.12 (INVALID)
- 8192.13 (INVALID)
- 8192.14 (INVALID)
- 8192.15 (VALID)
- 8192.20 (VALID)
- 8192.21 (INVALID)

Answer (score 0):

The code works fine for me in IE11, however there's a few things to note.

IE won't stop you from submitting the form unless you enter a value that it won't accept. You will get an error with any value entered with more than 2 digits after the decimal. e.g. `100.123` will fail.

In addition you won't see the stepper arrows in IE https://caniuse.com/#search=number%20input%20type and (as of the time of this answer) I believe this site should be updated to indicate that IE suffers from footnote #2 as it doesn't support/enforce the min/max values. So IE will accept values outside of your range like `-37.5` as well as `347000`.